# recursion in groovy (grails)

Tags: grails, groovy

I am trying to use recursion in groovy to traverse a tree relationship. The below code runs one cycle, upto  childNodes && recurClosure(childNodes ) , but doesn't call the closure recurClosure again. At that instant childNodes had two objects (array list)  same type as root.

In the code, recurClosure is defined and calls with a list of objects (root). It then iterates through each element and fines the child nodes (uses grails dsl for this).If the childNodes is not null, it recursively calls the parent method.

Should I break it up, or what is wrong?

```
def parentval 
def root = Domain.list()

def recurClosure
recurClosure = {inroot ->
  inroot.each {
    returnList << it
    parentval = it
    childNodes = Domain.withCriteria {
      eq('parent', parentval )
    }
  }
  childNodes && recurClosure(childNodes )
}(root)

return returnList
```

}

thanks in advance.

Update: The following exception is noted

```
    ERROR [2010-06-24 08:20:04,742] [groovy.grails.web.errors.GrailsExceptionResolver] Cannot invoke method call() on null object
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method call() on null object
    at com.bsr.test.DomainService$_closure2_closure7.doCall(com.bsr.test.DomainService:68)
    at com.bsr.test.DomainService$_closure2.doCall(com.bsr.test.DomainService:58)
    at com.bsr.test.DomainController$_closure3.doCall(DomainController.groovy:45)
    at com.bsr.test.DomainController$_closure3.doCall(DomainController.groovy)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ShiroFilter.executeChain(ShiroFilter.java:687)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ShiroFilter.doFilterInternal(ShiroFilter.java:616)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:81)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

Update 2: Now trying Daniel's suggestion.

```
{ inroot ->
    inroot.each {
        returnList << it
        parentval = it
        childNodes = Domain.withCriteria {
            eq('parent', parentval )
        }
           if(childNodes)
           call(childNodes)
    }
       /*if(childNodes)
        call(childNodes)*/

}(root)
```

In the above implementation, root is an arraylist, The inner closure takes each element out of it and recursively calls the anonymous closure. When I moved the 'call' inside the each closure, it doesn't call the outer anonymous closure, but the inroot.each {} itself. So, I get an error

```
ERROR [2010-06-24 08:47:46,438] [groovy.grails.web.errors.GrailsExceptionResolver] instance not of expected entity type: java.util.ArrayList is not a: com.bsr.test.Domain
```

I see a blog post about how to name the closure through ['this'](http://kasparov.skife.org/blog/src/groovy/imap-to-exchange.html) > I'll update my finding.. thanks

Update 3: The way to call the outer closure is  owner.call(childNodes)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is, that by

```
recurClosure = {
    [...]
}(root)
```

you don't assign the closure to `recurClosure`, but rather the *return value* of its invocation! Thus, of course, you can't call the closure via `recurClosure()`...

Two possible solutions:

First define the closure, and then call it separately, as air_blob suggested:

```
def recurClosure = {
    [...]
}
recurClosure(root)
```

Use the implicit `call()` function for recursion. This way you can even work with an anonymous closure. IMHO a very nice way to implement recursion in Groovy:

```
{ inroot ->
    inroot.each {
        returnList << it
        parentval = it
        childNodes = Domain.withCriteria {
            eq('parent', parentval )
        }
    }
    if(childNodes)
        call(childNodes)
}(root)
```

Two more comments on your code:

1. You may want to declare `returnList`: `def returnList = []`
2. While `childNodes && recurClosure(childNodes )` may do what you want, it's much more readable to sacrifice one more char and spell out the `if`.. ;-)
3. Don't you want to recursively call your closure *inside* the `each`?

Another (higher-level) remark on your code: If the parents and their children are of the same type (`Domain`), won't `Domain.list()` actually return all children, too? Is there really a need for traversing the tree manually?

Comment: Daniel.. excited to see your answer, as it catches all the mistakes in the code.. Well, I adapted my code listing to make it simpler for the question. So, 1. I did defined returnList as an array list. 2. I do agree 3. You are right, that what I wanted (I tried moving the statement in and out of that closure to see the effect). I certainly was not doing a list() on the domain class, infact get it from another table. I never intented to mislead an expert like you (both in groovy and grails :-|) .. I am trying out your anonymous closure implementation .. will update in a bit .. thanks a lot

Comment: Daniel, I have updated the question with some more details.. now the question is, how to invoke the outer anonymous closure through 'call'. thanks again.

Comment: thanks.. found the solution to call the outer closure. I need to invoke owner.call(childNodes) .. thanks again for ur detailed answer.

Answer (score 2):

Do you get any exceptions?
Have you tried invoking it separately like this:

```
def recurClosure
recurClosure = {inroot ->
  [... stuff ...]
}

recurClosure(root)
```

What exactly do you want to do in this line:

```
childNodes && recurClosure(childNodes )
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggetions.. I have updated with the exception. The intention of childNodes && recurClosure(childNodes ) was to continue the recursion until the childnode is null. May be the array list wont be null, so I tried (childNodes.size() > 0) && recurClosure(childNodes ) but same result. From the exception it seems like it can't access the closure.